# Recording an acoustic guitar using plain simple laptop mic

Tags: acoustic-guitar, recording, microphones

I had a Windows 7 laptop and the recording was doing acoustic cancellations. After disabling it the recordings (from control panel->settings->microphone) were pretty decent.

Now I have a Window 10 laptop and the option of acoustic cancellations is not present, the problem is the sound of guitar is very bland now. It doesn't capture any high notes.

Please suggest if I can do something.

Thanks...

Comment: Have you changed computer or just upgraded the OS in the same computer? If you changed computer, the difference in performance could be due to many things, starting with the hw. If you just upgraded the OS on the same computer, check that you have installed the latest version of the drivers from the soundboard manufacturer, don't just rely on windows default drivers.

Comment: What is an "acoustic cancellation"? Do you mean noise cancellation?

Answer (score 1):

While I use 7 myself, this post - http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-2745835/windows-microphone-noise-cancelling-suppresion-working.html - mentions it's under

```
Sound>Recording>Microphone>Enhancements
```